# Trying to understand vim mapping

Tags: vim

I copied this keymap for latex [1], but I don't understand the `<++><Esc>T{i`. When I write `,it`, the `\textit{}<++>` appears. First, I don't know what are the <++> and how to deal with them. Then, why this mapping has `<Esc>T{i`? What is its purpose?

[1] `autocmd FileType tex inoremap ,it \textit{}<++><Esc>T{i`

Answer (score 2):

- `<++>` is probably a placeholder from latex-suite. You can jump to the next placeholder with `<C-J>` in insert if you have the plugin. Look [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-macros.html#place-holders).
- `<Esc>` puts you in normal mode
- `T{` moves 'til the previous `{`, see [`:h T`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#T)
- `i` puts you back in insert mode.

If you don't want to use latex-suite, you could have all your snippets with [UltiSnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) and [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) with which you can enter `ita<Tab>` which gives you the same behaviour (with `<c-j>` jump as well).